# JSON parsing issue in a google map API web application

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I am developing a "google maps API" based website, and I have a JSON file to parse. My code works fine on my laptop when I use chrome to test. Of course I used the "--allow-file-access-from-files" command to avoid the "same origin" protocol. However, the code don't work on my inMotion Hosting server. It yields a error:"marker feed error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o". Here is my code:

```
    function loadJson() {   
      // JSON Parser  
      var feedSource = "json/markers07022014.json";
       $.ajax({
            url: feedSource,
            success: function(data){
             try{
               //console.log("feed "+data);
               //var jsonData = eval("(" + data + ")");
               var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

              for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.markers.length; i++) {     
                var output = [];
                fireName[i]= jsonData.markers[i].name;
                output["name"] =      jsonData.markers[i].name;
                output["summary"] =   jsonData.markers[i].summary;
                output["url"] =       jsonData.markers[i].url;
                output["lat"] =       Math.round(jsonData.markers[i].lat*100)/100;
                output["lng"] =       Math.round(jsonData.markers[i].lng*100)/100;
                output["contained"] = jsonData.markers[i].contained;
                //todo new google.maps.LatLng(defLat, defLng)
                //output["point"] =     new GLatLng(parseFloat(jsonData.markers[i].lat), parseFloat(jsonData.markers[i].lng));
                 output["point"] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jsonData.markers[i].lat), parseFloat(jsonData.markers[i].lng));
                 fireAddress[i]=output["point"];

                // skip over incident details point for current incident
                if (output["lat"] != detailLat || output["lng"] != detailLng) {   

                  var marker = createMarker(output);


                } 
                //if necessary createList of makers and windows if 

              }
            } catch (anErr){
              console.log("marker feed error "+anErr);
            }
           }
         });
      }
```